# Print 4 Grids to 4 pieces of paper

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, vb.net-2010

Using Silverlight 5 and VB.Net, I'm trying to print 4 Grids from LayoutRoot to 4 separate pieces of paper as follows, but I only get the last Grid printed. I understand why this is, but how should I be doing it? I scale the grids to 75% of their original size as this gets them to fit on a portrait oriented peice of paper widthwise.

Thanks.

```
Imports System.Windows.Printing

Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl
    Public WithEvents pd As New PrintDocument

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        pd.Print("My Test Print")
        Call ScaleUp()
    End Sub

    Private Sub pd_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pd.PrintPage
        Dim ScaleDown As New ScaleTransform
        ScaleDown.ScaleX = "0.75"
        ScaleDown.ScaleY = "0.75"
        CompChartGrid.RenderTransform = ScaleDown
        AttChartGrid.RenderTransform = ScaleDown
        CompDetGrid.RenderTransform = ScaleDown
        AttDetGrid.RenderTransform = ScaleDown
        e.PageVisual = CompChartGrid
        e.HasMorePages = True
        e.PageVisual = AttChartGrid
        e.HasMorePages = True
        e.PageVisual = CompDetGrid
        e.HasMorePages = True
        e.PageVisual = AttDetGrid
        e.HasMorePages = False
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. The trick is that the pd_PrintPage method will be called for each page to be printed. In your case, only the last page is printed because you are overwriting your intended visuals.

Try something like this instead:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = new PrintDocument();

    var pages = new Stack<UIElement>();
    pages.Push(AttDetGrid);
    pages.Push(CompDetGrid);
    pages.Push(AttChartGrid);
    pages.Push(CompChartGrid);

    doc.PrintPage += (x, y) =>
        {
            if (pages.Count > 0)
            {
                y.PageVisual = pages.Pop();
                y.HasMorePages = pages.Count > 0;
            }
        };

    doc.Print("My Printed document name");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, I did it like this in the end:

```
Private Sub pd_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pd.PrintPage

        Static Counter As Integer = 1
        If Counter = 1 Then
            Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Grid1)
            PrintSurface.Children.Add(Grid1)
            e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
            Counter += 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Counter = 2 Then
            Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Grid2)
            PrintSurface.Children.Add(Grid2)
            e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
            Counter += 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Counter = 3 Then
            Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Grid3)
            PrintSurface.Children.Add(Grid3)
            e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
            Counter += 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Counter = 4 Then
            Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Grid4)
            PrintSurface.Children.Add(Grid4)
            e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
            Counter += 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Counter = 5 Then
            Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Grid5)
            PrintSurface.Children.Add(Grid5)
            e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
            Counter += 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Counter = 6 Then
            Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(Grid6)
            PrintSurface.Children.Add(Grid6)
            e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
            e.HasMorePages = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End Sub
```